# error in configuration for biz-Talk 2009

Tags: sql-server, single-sign-on, biztalk

I have 2 server server_1 and server_2,in server_1 where is installed SQL server and in the server_2 the biz-Talk server 2009 is installed
when i want to configure biz-Talk server in the first step of configuration SSO configuration there are the following error"the database server that you specified cannot be reached .." and the database server name of sql server is correct and the two server are connected.
can anyone help me please!

Comment: Firewall? Protocol settings, have you checked the connections settings in SQL Configuration Manager? Basically this have nothing to do with BizTalk but probably just with you current SQL Server settings

Comment: there are no firewall! and i checked the confiquration but i think that the problem is in SPN because another server can connect to the server where is located sqlserver bu the server of biztalk cannot be acces!!